# prevent duplicate submission of forms on jsp pages

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts2

Hi all
I've got some jsp pages and im using struts to handle my forms.
After submitting a form by user, the url shown in address bar becomes somthing.action, so when the user refreshes the page, the forms gets submitted again.
How can I handle this?
after submission of a form, Is there any possible way to show a ".jsp" url instead of a ".action" in the address bar?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use [redirect-after-post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Either `response.sendRedirect("foo.jsp")`, or [see here](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/redirect-action-result.html) or [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/54234/Struts/acheive-Send-Redirect-Struts) (depending on what exactly your code is).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Struts 2, it has a Token interceptor, to prevent duplicate form submissions -

http://struts.apache.org/2.1.2/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/TokenInterceptor.html

And an example: https://cwiki.apache.org/WW/token-interceptor.html

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect user to some page (it can by same as form) after you make action, it will not send post data if page will by refreshed.